# Is sleep exercise possible?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, biology, humans

Is is possible to put someone to sleep and, while they are sleeping, attach muscle stimulating pads, causing the muscles to do work and causing exercise to be done without consciousness?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding, please check that the edit I have done keeps the sense of the question you wanted to post. Also, science based tag is not to be used alone. Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to find out more about our community.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not clearly about worldbuilding and it's something you can figure out with a bit of research.  If your research doesn't cover every aspect, ask about what you couldn't find out.

Comment: @Cyn not being well-researched is not a reason to vote to close - it is a reason to downvote (hover of the downvote option) - as even the general guidelines only say "should contain". I will agree that this seem a bad fit for worldbuilding (not building a world)

Comment: I try not to downvote, in part because I don't want to give up rep to do it.  I probably would not have VTC if the only issue were the lack of research, but, frankly, that lack is precisely what makes the question too broad.  It's a "tell me everything you know about this subject" type question.

Comment: @Cyn downvoting questions has not cost rep [since 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/)

Comment: @JGreenwell what?  I though it cost me a point.  Answers and questions both.

Comment: @Cyn I don't know if the new "un-welcoming wagon" policies will change this with the focus moving to questions, IMHO, but for now - downvotes on questions cost 0 rep

Comment: @JGreenwell Thanks.  I didn't know.  I read the rules and various parts of the FAQ and many I've re-read, but somehow that bit didn't stick.  I will do more question downvoting :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is perfectly possible.

[This paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25296344), *Neuromuscular electrical stimulation prevents muscle wasting in critically ill comatose patients*, details that it is indeed a good idea.

> Neuromuscular electrical stimulation (NMES) represents an effective method to stimulate muscle protein synthesis and alleviate muscle disuse atrophy in healthy subjects. We investigated the efficacy of twice-daily NMES to alleviate muscle loss in six fully sedated ICU patients admitted for acute critical illness.
>
> One leg was subjected to twice-daily NMES of the quadriceps muscle for a period of 7 ± 1 day whereas the other leg acted as a non-stimulated control (CON). No muscle atrophy was observed in the stimulated leg.
>
> In conclusion, NMES represents an effective and feasible interventional strategy to prevent skeletal muscle atrophy in critically ill comatose patients.

Comment: Good answer, assuming the OP doesn't want to *grow* muscles like a body builder during sleep. And keep in mind that electrode pads can only stimulate surface muscles, so the patients would suffer atrophy in core muscles and the heart nonetheless.

Comment: @Elmy If the heart isn't working long enough to suffer from atrophy you may have bigger problems.

Comment: @Bellerophon Maybe clinical atrophy is too strong of a word, I was referring to the difference in size and strength of a heart of a couch potato compared to a trained athlete. What use is all your muscle mass if your heart cannot keep up with the demand for blood?